# Google Analytics - Data Length of the Dimension & Metrics

Tags: api, google-app-engine, google-analytics, metrics, dimensions

Team,

We have a daily data pull for Google Analytics, we get Source, Geo, Geo Network,Device & AdWords data into SQL Server for reporting purpose.

Today we got the production failure because of the lengthy keyword dimension data from Google. Is there a way to figure out all the column data sizes? Including the list of Dimension & Metrics? Please share if there is a place where it is all defined.

Thanks
Senthil

Comment: Look in the Dimensions and metrics reference (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference) . E.g. max length for campaign keywords is defined asa 500bytes.

Comment: thanks Eike.. I am looking for PagePath & Keyword Dimensions, i am not seeing them there. Is there an another place i can took ?

Comment: Pagepath is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#page with 2048 Bytes (does not include the domain which goes into a separate field "host". A tracking request has a maximum size of 8KB, so you can be reasonably sure no field will be longer than that.

Comment: thanks Eike. I am getting the data into SQL Server, which has the data limitation on the table columns. What would be the 8KB equal varchar?? Please assist ..

Comment: I can't really assist with SQL server. Judging by the docs I'd say that all practical use cases could be covered with the nvarchar datatype, but that's guessing on my part - maybe you can start an extra question with the appropriate tag.

Comment: Thanks Eike for your assistance, appreciate it .